# Проблема с функцией range в python

Tags: python, функции

Ни как не могу разобраться с заданием связанным с функцией range.
Нужно написать функцию  которая получает число и увеличивает его вдвое .В цикле, чтобы трижды увеличивал  вдвое число , с выводом каждого результата в отдельной строке. Например : при вводе цифры 2 получаем
4
8
16

Мой неправильный код:

```
n = int(input())

for doubles in range(1,4):
    s = n ** 2
    print(s * doubles)
```

Я не понимаю как реализовать умножение числа чтобы цифра не умножалось на диапазон указанный в range.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы правильно увеличивать число вдвое и выводить результаты в цикле, необходимо изменить ваш код следующим образом:

```
n = int(input())

for _ in range(3):
    n *= 2  # Увеличиваем число n вдвое
    print(n)
```

Comment: `in range(3)` достаточно

Comment: Кст, да, спасибо

Comment: Да . Все работает, спасибо. Но можете мне объяснить что я делал не так .

Comment: @andrew Вместо умножения возводили в квадрат, каждую итерацию

Answer (score 0):

Если оставить возведение в степень, то код должен быть такой:

```py
n = int(input())

for i in range(2,5):
    s = n ** i
    print(s)
```

Но вариант с постепенным домножением более оптимальный, конечно.